# Spring RestTemplate as a Spring Service

Tags: spring, rest, resttemplate, spring-io

I have developed a REST server with our app specific APIs. we also have deployed a different rest Job server into another location. Currently the way I am doing is .

```
@RestController
public class SparkJobController  {

    @Autowired
    private IJobSchedulerService jobService;
...
```

And the Service Implementation is

```
@Service(value="jobService")
public class JobSchedulerServiceImpl implements IJobSchedulerService {

    @Override
    public Map triggerJob(String context) {

        Map<String, ?> s = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
//      restTemplate call to other REST API. and returns Map.
    ...     
}
```

My question is , Is my approach correct ? Or Does Spring framework enables us to use some predefined APIs which can help to use ***RESTTemplate as a Service***

[EDIT] : the deployed REST service is third party application.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and havent' seen yet a way to implement RestTemplate as a service.

I have seen RestTemplate defined in the bean config and auto wired in - https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=546

To summarize, most of the examples I have seen use Resttemplate, similar to how you have implemented in your code.

Comment: thanks for the link, however its jus DI. Was wondering how folks with such dependency manage.

Comment: i am yet to see a different way to do this...most i have seen are plain old school DI ..

Comment: I am exploring the same. will update here with my conclusion and approach.